# Flutter Future Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

This question is very important for me to understand how FutureProvider works in Flutter.
At the end I will have 3 or 4 Future Providers (1xSharedPreferences, 3xSqflite).

My problem is that I couldn't update the data. I create UserProfile object (run-time) but couldn't update that particular object. Instead of I'm updating the source of the object. I couldn't find a solution because all future provider examples are related with Json and really difficult to understand for my knowledge level.

Here is my code;
MAIN.DART FILE

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserService userService = UserService();
    return FutureProvider<UserProfile>(
      create: (context) => userService.fetchUserProfile(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

HOME_PAGE.DART FILE

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UserProfile userData = Provider.of<UserProfile>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Consumer<UserProfile>(
        builder: (context, value, widget) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Text('User ID & Name : ${value.id} / ${value.name}'),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  UserService dataChanger = UserService();
                  dataChanger.changeUserName();
                },
                child: Text('Press'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

USER.DART FILE

```
class UserProfile {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  UserProfile({this.id, this.name});
}
```

USER_SERVICES.DART FILE

```
class UserService {
  Future<UserProfile> fetchUserProfile() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getInt('ID') == null) {await prefs.setInt('ID', 1);}
    if (prefs.getString('NAME') == null) {await prefs.setString('NAME', 'Brad Pitt');}
    UserProfile userProfile = UserProfile(
        id: prefs.getInt('ID'),
        name: prefs.getString('NAME'),
    );
    return userProfile;
  }

  Future<void> changeUserName() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('NAME', 'Angelina Julie');
  }
}
```

I'll ve appreciated if someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your app not update username on pressing the button?

Comment: Yes. changeUserName function is for this.(double checked, the entry update completes successfully.) But the future provider does not aware about this change. Somehow it isn't tracking. I tried value constructor and other possible scenarios. Everytime provider can't update itself.

Comment: I recommend you to read the FutureProvider section in this blog, https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd